# Response.Redirect big news

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect

I got a strange phenomenon when using Response.Redirect in my asp.net app, here is the thing:

```
Response.Redirect("~/somepage.aspx");
```

when the page is just in root of virtual dir, it will take almostly 15 milliseconds to get(find) the page

```
Response.Redirect("~/somedir/somepage.aspx");
```

when I move the page to a dir, it will take almostly 2 seconds to get(find) the page,  the time is unbearable for browsing website, and I tried lots of ways to fix it eventually still don't know why this happen, could you nice guys give me any addvices,  thanks a lot.
btw, somepage.aspx have nothing in it, except for two words in body node: "help me".

p.s. there are 72 aspx pages in somedir,  about 10 aspx pages in root dir.

I found some clue, I create a new dir newdir with only somepage.aspx in it, then the time spent for getting the page is 15 milliseconds again, so the test leads me to the this conclusion: the time Response.Redirect works is based on the number of files in dir, mayber I 'm wrong about it, but that's the only fact I got.

Comment: it could be a virus problem such as desktop.ini and folder.htt these virus can slow down performance 
simple search and delete while show all files checked in tools>option>view
secondly delete web folder in C:\WINDOWS\web

Comment: I take your advices into serious consideration, thank you #skhurams #Siva Charan

Comment: Works on my machine. Can you provide a *minimal* working sample that reproduces the problem?

Comment: use precompile, my problem is solved, thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not the problem with Response.Redirect.

Actually problem would be based on the content & controls on the page, which is taking time to load all the information.